# RichFaces suggestionbox not shown if request takes more than 1.5 seconds

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces, seam

In a JSF page, I have an input and a suggestion box. Normally, when I input text into:

```
h:inputText
```

The suggestionBox will begin to show suggested results, which is correct.
However, the problem is that, if the request when I input text takes long to have response, the suggestionBox is not shown at all.
I use firebug, and if request takes > 1.5 sec, the suggestion will fail.
After 1.5 sec, I still see the response, with the correct suggested results, however, no refresh.

What can be the cause? In my web application, there are many other things that run much longer and get refreshed successfully.

I use Richfaces 3.3.3

UPDATE1: To add more, if the request take 1.59 sec, the suggestion appear, then fade out right away

UPDATE2: I solved this by put the suggestion and input into

```
a4j:region
```

However, I still don't understand why.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I use richfaces, rich:suggestionbox tag

Comment: You should maybe consider not using a suggestion box if the request can normally last more than 1.5 seconds. You can be sure that a normal user won't wait so long and will click elsewhere in the screen, what will automatically close the suggestion box as soon as it appears.

Answer (score 1):

The [`suggestionBox` component of RichFaces](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/suggestionbox.html) has a `timeout` attribute which defines:

> Response waiting time on a particular request. If a response is not received during this time, the request is aborted

You could try to increase the timeout value and test if it solves your problem.

Note that you could define the `timeout` for all the Ajax requests in a view using the `a4j:queue`.

NB: since this is not specified, I checked for RichFaces 3.x but there should be something similar with RichFaces 4.x.

Comment: Yes I know this attribute too. I set the timeout to 1 second, and if the request takes more than that, it is discarded (in Firebug I see the request is marked with red). Setting a bigger timeout (I try 5 seconds) doesn't help because in my case, I still receive the correct response, with suggested results. The problem is that the page doesn't refresh with these new data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be inside the richfaces suggestionbox if you are using Richfaces 4.x.
When I was upgrading from Richfaces 3 to 4th version there were a lot of problems with suggestionbox. It was just not showing up on complex pages. I ended with replacing richfaces suggestionbox with JQuery UI sugestionbox and some Spring MVC controllers for loading suggestions.

If you are using Richfaces 4.3.x and using using JQuery UI for suggestionbox is not an options you can try to downgrade to Richfaces 4.2.x. I remember that when I was doing this suggestiongs started to appear on the page but at this place you can have other issues with Richfaces.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention my Richfaces version. Thanks anyway